# Car would start roughly and then coast with cyclic acceleration (foot not on peddle)

Tags: chevrolet, troubleshooting, cavalier

For a car I had a few years ago ('96 Cavalier) I ran into an issue where I would turn the key, and the car would shake while starting. After it started I could feel the engine rev in a cyclic pattern (I timed it and it repeated fairly consistently). After putting the car in gear I would coast for a moment without my foot on the peddle and the car would accelerate slightly every time the motor would hit that cyclic rev. When depressing the accelerator the car would just continue that pattern with more gusto, but would top out at about halfway down (accelerator peddle that is). After trying to figure out what the problem was myself, I had it towed to a mechanic and after leaving it there for three days they called and said that when they started the car nothing was wrong. They attempted to leave it running a while and drive it around to attempt to replicate the issue, but to no avail. So I picked up my car and never had the issue again for the year or so I had it before I sold it.

As I mentioned above I do not have the car, I was just wondering if anyone has had this issue before or had any idea what it could be. I thought perhaps it was a misfire in the cylinder, since I had that cyclic revving.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the Intake Air Control (IAC) valve, but this wouldn't explain why it just suddenly stopped when taken to the garage. Cars do not become suddenly afraid of the mechanic and start working right (no matter how often I quip then do!). I'm wondering if the mechanic did some minor cleaning and it started working right and they decided it wasn't worth their trouble to charge you for it.

Comment: It was definitely very puzzling. I just decided that since no one could figure out what was wrong, and the problem wouldn't replicate itself, that I shouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth.

Answer (score 0):

It could be moisture in the spark plugs, did you have it washed (especially the engine). If that is the case, the engine is running on few cylinders until the engine's heath evaporates the water around the plugs and then suddenly everything is back to normal.